# Keyboard Accessibility - links not getting focus on tabbing - Safari Browser

Tags: safari, keyboard, anchor, accessibility, tabbing

I'm facing an accessibility issue with Safari browser on tabbing. Anchor tags are not getting focus on tabbing.
I have checked with and without tabindex. Setting tabindex="0",  but nothing changed, not sure this is a bug in Safari or not. Tested in other websites including https://www.microsoft.com , the same experience.

Safari Version 10.1.1 (11603.2.5)
Mac : OS X El Capitan

Button element is getting focus, only issue is with anchor tag

```
<a id="footer-linkedin-link" target="_blank" class="social-footer-icon" aria-label="Follow on LinkedIn" href="https://www.linkedin.com/"></a>
```

Any valuable inputs will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/14/enable-tab-key-navigation-safari/

Comment: Thanks for the information. This fixed the issue.

Comment: @ajeshrkurup I think that this issue will be really fixed when Safari will make this the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an empty anchor tag - there's nothing to tab to.  That's an HTML validation error so browsers may handle it differently.  Without your CSS I'm not sure exactly what you should do, but I'm guessing you really want something like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
    <span id="footer-linkedin-link" class="social-footer-icon" role="img" aria-label="Follow on LinkedIn" ></span>
</a>
```

The icon being inserted with CSS needs to be the content within the anchor, be properly cast as an image using `role="img"`, and that should have the `aria-label`.

Comment: already commented above that it is resolved by changing above setting. Also I have mentioned that it is tested across other pages to make sure it is not an issue with my webpage. There is no role for CSS and I'm not sure why you are changing the HTML itself  by adding a <span> tag.

Comment: I understand your issue was related to the Safari tabbing setting; however, your anchor tag has no content in your code.  Unless you purposely left that out for brevity, that's an accessibility problem.